# gmaps4rails - many markers, one location - how to view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I am wondering how to deal with the situation where one location may have many markers.

I am using gmaps4rails and rails 3

does this have something to do with the "do_clustering" property of the gmaps?

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 0):

excellent, just found "randomize" in the documentation! perfect:

{:data => @json, :options => { :do_clustering => true, randomize: true}   }) %>